# Find the set of values of $x$ for which the inequality $\ln(1+x)>\frac{x}{1+x}$ is valid.

Tags: calculus

> Find the set of values of $x$ for which the inequality $\ln(1+x)>\frac{x}{1+x}$ is valid.

My work.
Let $f(x)=\ln(1+x)-\frac{x}{1+x}$ then 
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}>0$$ for $x>0$, 
so $\ln(1+x)>\frac{x}{1+x}$ for $x>0$.

But the answer given in my book is $(-1,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. The function $f$ is defined for $x>-1$. You showed that function $f$ is strictly increasing in $(0,+\infty)$ (because $f'>0$) and it is strictly decreasing in $(-1,0)$ (because $f'<0$). Hence $f$ has a minimum point at $x=0$ where $f(0)=0$. So the inequality $f(x)>0$ holds iff $x\in (-1,0)\cup (0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Also $ f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}<0$ for $x<0$
so $f(x) > f(0) = 0$ for $x<0$