# Prove by Mean Value Theorem $\ln(1+x) \ge\frac{x}{1+x}$ for $x>-1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, mean-value-theorem

Prove for $\;x>-1\,,\,\;\ln(1+x)\geqslant\dfrac{x}{1+x}\,.$

I have proved that for every $\,x>0\,,\;\ln(1+x)\geqslant\dfrac{x}{1+x}\,.$

However, I am not sure if it is suitable for $\,x>-1\,.$

MY WORK

Taking $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$, which is differentiable on $(0,x)$ and continuous on $[0,x]$. By using Mean Value Theorem, there exist $c$ in $(0,x)$ such that $$f'(c)=\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\dfrac{1}{1+c}$$
$$\ln(1+x)=\frac{x}{1+c}$$

Since $0<c<x$, $$\dfrac{x}{1+c}>\dfrac{t}{1+t}$$

therefore, $$\ln(1+x)>\dfrac{x}{1+x}$$ for $x>0$

Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How did you prove it for $x > 0$? Where does your proof fail for $-1 < x \le 0$?

Comment: could you show what your proof was for $x>0$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2333217/42969

Comment: Recall that $1+u\leq e^u$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$. Now $\frac{1}{1+t}=1-\frac{t}{1+t}\leq \exp(-\frac{t}{1+t})$. Taking logarithm on all sides yield what you want (provided that $1+t>0$).

Answer (score 1):

For $x<0$, $$ln(1+x)=\frac{x}{1+c}=-\frac{|x|}{|1+c|}\ge -\frac{|x|}{|1-|x||}=\frac{x}{1+x}$$
where $c\in (x,0)$.

Comment: How do you get to $x/(1+c)$

Comment: @mathsdummie1234 $\frac{ln(1+x)-ln(1)}{(1+x)-1}=(ln(1+x))’|_{x=c}$ for some $c\in(x,0)$.

Comment: Got it. you re basically constructing a closed intervall with a variable lower bound